# General Gson Serialization of API types

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson, generalization

I am working with an API that can have different types for it's attributes

The attributes can either be Ids or Objects

I want to build a generalized type that handles this for me with Gson serialization.

Example:

```
"platforms": [
        6
    ]

"platforms": [
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "PC (Microsoft Windows)",
        "slug": "win",
        "url": "https://www.igdb.com/platforms/win",
        "created_at": 1297639288000,
        "updated_at": 1470063140518,
        "website": "http://windows.microsoft.com/",
        "alternative_name": "mswin"
    }
]
```

I am working with Kotlin and have started building my Generalizable class

```
data class ObjectType<T>(
        var Id: Long? = null,
        var expand: T? = null
)
```

I am currently stuck in constructing my JsonDeserializer, as it needs a return of type T which in my case can be both an Int or an Object. I have tried to replace the T with ObjectType which works 'better' but cannot handle the cases when the JSON is an array.

I am currently trying to make it work with just the Generalized Type T as I can set the type as List> instead.

Current Implementation:

```
class ObjectDeserializer<T> : JsonDeserializer<T> {

    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): T {
        if (json != null) {

            if (json.isJsonArray) {

                val struct: T = Gson().fromJson(json, T::class.java) as T
                return struct
            } else {
                val id = Gson().fromJson(json, Long::class.java)
                //return ObjectType(id, null)
            }

        }

        return T as T
    }
}
```

I would love some input on how to solve this.

Comment: Do you have any control over that API? Because that strikes me as a terrible design choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation has some issues and inconsistencies. First you have to make sure to deserialize `ObjectType<T>`. Thus you have to declare the class as:

```
class ObjectDeserializer<T> : JsonDeserializer<ObjectType<T>>
```

It would also be easier to assume that all parameters are non-null:

```
override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type,
                         context: JsonDeserializationContext): ObjectType<T>
```

Now you can use `typeOfT` which is actually the type of `T` in `JsonDeserializer`, not in `ObjectDeserializer`. Therefore it's the type of `ObjectType<T>` you need to deserialize. To move to the next step you need to find the actual type of T:

```
val objectTypeType = typeOfT as ParameterizedType
val actualTypeOfT = objectTypeType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]
```

As the next step you need to figure out the contents of `json`. In your case you won't ever find an array, but an object or a long:

```
return if (json.isJsonObject()) {
    val struct: T = context.deserialize(json, actualTypeOfT)
    ObjectType(expand = struct)
} else {
    val id = json.getAsLong()
    ObjectType(Id = id)
}
```

Here you return the `ObjectType` instances without any error handling, which you might need to add as well.

Then you should provide this deserializer to *Gson* by:

```
registerTypeAdapter(ObjectType::class.java, ObjectDeserializer<Any>())
```

Whenever *Gson* needs to deserialize an `ObjectType<TheType>`, it finds the instance of `ObjectDeserializer` and provides `ObjectType<TheType>` as `typeOfT` to `deserialize`.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply, can only work on this during the weekends.. 
I tried your solution but it does not seem to work using the ParameterizedType as i get a class cast exception 

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`

But if i have understood this correctly then i should have a Type back from  the actualTypeOfT. Why not only use typeOfT?

Comment: The `typeOfT` should be of type `ObjectType<T>`. How do you actually call `Gson` for converting the input _Json_? And how do you register the deserializer?

Comment: The typeOfT is not ObjectType<T> but the main object Game 
`data class Game (
        val id: Long? = null,
        val name: String? = null,
        ......
       val developers: List<ObjectType<Company>>? = null,
        val publishers: List<ObjectType<Company>>? = null,`

Comment: `val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(com.igdb.igdbmainapp.kotlin.Game::class.java, ObjectDeserializer<List<ObjectType<GenreTheme>>>()).create()`

Comment: But how should that look? 
I thought i did just that. And the ObjectType needs a type anyhow
I'm not sure that i follow.